# Values of type must be comptime-known

Tags: zig

I've the below in my code:

```
var routeRegister = std.StringHashMap(*const fn (response: *http.Server.Response) void).init(allocator);
try routes.init(&routeRegister);
defer routeRegister.deinit();

const some_data_info = @typeInfo(@TypeOf(routeRegister));
print("{}\n", .{some_data_info});
```

But I got the below error:

```
/usr/lib/zig/std/fmt.zig:662:22: error: values of type '[]const builtin.Type.StructField' must be comptime-known, but index value is runtime-known
                for (value, 0..) |elem, i| {
                     ^~~~~
/usr/lib/zig/std/builtin.zig:318:15: note: struct requires comptime because of this field
        type: type,
              ^~~~
/usr/lib/zig/std/builtin.zig:318:15: note: types are not available at runtime
        type: type,
              ^~~~
/usr/lib/zig/std/builtin.zig:321:20: note: struct requires comptime because of this field
        alignment: comptime_int,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried:

```js
var routeRegister = comptime std.StringHashMap(*const fn (response: *http.Server.Response) void);
try routeRegister.init(allocator);
```

But got:

```
server.zig:99:13: error: variable of type 'type' must be const or comptime
        var routeRegister = comptime std.StringHashMap(*const fn (response: *http.Server.Response) void);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
server.zig:99:13: note: types are not available at runtime
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 what is wrong in my code, and how to fix it?

Comment: What is wrong in the first or in the second error?

Comment: @mkrieger1 to solve my issue I need to know what is wrong in the first error, to learn want to solve both errors.

Comment: Does the first error message point to any specific location in your code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it appeared once I added the line `const some_data_info = @typeInfo(@TypeOf(routeRegister));`

Comment: Is the error still there if you remove the `@typeInfo`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it worked but I go memory leack `error(gpa): memory address 0x7f53eb9bd300 leaked: `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second error occurs because [`std.StringHashMap`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:StringHashMap) returns a type. Just declare it constant (you can also declare it outside of any function):

```
const RouteRegister = std.StringHashMap(*const fn (response: *http.Server.Response) void);
var routeRegister = RouteRegister.init(allocator);
```

The first error occurs because [`@typeInfo`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#typeInfo) returns [`std.builtin.Type`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:builtin.Type), which cannot be formatted by the default formatter. Just remove `@typeInfo` and print the `type` directly:

```
print("{}\n", .{ @TypeOf(routeRegister) });
// or just
print("{}\n", .{ RouteRegister });
```